# Given the numeric value of a particular enum type, how can I retrieve the name?

Tags: java

I'm trying to set up my enum so that it has a list of names and retrieve a particular name given that value.

Example:
enum {Vanilla, Chocolate, Strawberry};

Given 0, return Vanilla.
Given 1, return Chocolate.
Given 2, return Strawberry.

I haven't been able to find any methods that come with the Java Enum class to do this out of the box.  I'm thinking of writing my own that dumps the values into an array and then use binary search to return them, given a particular number.

Is there something built in however that would be better?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have to implement it in the Enum. Like this:

```
public enum MyEnum {
  VANILLA(0), CHOCOLATE(1), STRAWBERRY(2);

  private int i;

  private MyEnum(int i) {
     this.i = i;
  }

  public static MyEnum getFoodById(int id) trhows IllegalArgumentException {
     MyEnum result = null;
     switch (id):
       case 0: {
         result = MyEnum.VANILLA;
         break;
       }
       case 1: {
         result = MyEnum.CHOCOLATE;
         break;
       }
       case 2: {
         result = MyEnum.STRAWBERRY;
         break;
       }
       default : { 
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid id ...");
       }
   }
   return result;
}
```

Comment: This is right because is not a good idea to use the "internal index" of the enum than can change if you refactor the code (reordening the list). In this way you are sure of what number is assigned to every object.

Comment: Of course. Vote up :)

Comment: +1 for the correct approach.

Comment: That won't work... actually even compile for that matters. `i` in the switch should be `id`.

Comment: Can you tell me what the pro's/ cons are over this approach over a for loop(as in my answer below)? Having to add a case every time we add an enum seems like an unnecessary overhead. It also has the potential to create bugs in your code?

Comment: I agree. Just wrote it like that for the specific case. :)

Answer (score 3):

If your id corresponds to the enum item's position, you can use the built-in `values()` and `ordinal()`-Methods.

```
// to enum
int intValue = 0;
CustomEnum item = CustomEnum.values()[intValue];

// to int
CustomEnum item = CustomEnum.SOME_ITEM;
int intValue = item.ordinal();
```

Comment: It is not a good practice to use the internal values of the enum, can change if you reorder the list in the source code.

Comment: That's why I wrote "If your id corresponds to the enum item's position"

Answer (score 2):

You can use EnumMap. You can look at [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2046680) for solution and example.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it this way:

public enum IntEnum {

```
Vanilla(0), Chocolate(1), Strawberry(2);

private int value;

IntEnum(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public int getValue() {
    return value;
}

public static IntEnum getEnum(int intValue) {
    Integer value = intValue;

    if (value == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    for (IntEnum v : values())
        if (value.equals(v.getValue()))
            return v;
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}



public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(IntEnum.getEnum(1));         
}
```

}

Comment: Should use `int` directly instead of `Integer`, avoid the possibility of the `null` value passed to your method.

Answer (score 0):

Enums do allow for built in functions.

```
public enum Flavor
{
    VANILLA("Vanilla"),
    CHOCOLATE("Chocolate"),
    STRAWBERRY("Strawberry");

    private final String desc;

    Flavor(String desc)
    {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getDesc()
    {
        return desc;
    }
}
```

Comment: How's this related to the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum Flavor {
    Vanilla, Chocolate, Strawberry
}

Flavor v = Flavor.values()[0];

String name = v.name(); // "Vanilla"
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name()

Comment: This is not how enums work in java.

Comment: @FDinoff what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the values() result:

```
enum Flavours {Vanilla, Chocolate, Strawberry}

assertTrue(Flavours.Vanilla == Flavours.values()[0]);
```